# Given $2xf(x)+(x-3)f(\frac{1}{1-x})=4x^2-10x-\frac{1}{2}$, find $f(x)$.

Tags: functions, functional-equations

> Given$$2xf(x)+(x-3)f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=4x^2-10x-\frac{1}{2}$$ Find $f(x)$.

This's the first time I see this kind of question, I have no idea. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Since on the RHS, degree is 2. I can not have $f(x)$ with degree more than 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** In equatoin
$$
2xf(x)+(x-3)f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=4x^2-10x-\frac{1}{2}\tag{1}
$$
make change of variables $x\to 1/(1-x)$ to get
$$
\frac{2}{1-x}f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)+\frac{3x-2}{1-x}f\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)=-\frac{x^2-22x+13}{2(1-x)^2}\tag{2}
$$
and make the same change one more time to get
$$
\frac{2 (x-1)}{x}f\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)-\frac{(2 x+1)
f(x)}{x}=\frac{4}{x^2}+\frac{2}{x}-\frac{13}{2}\tag{2}
$$
From $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$ you can find 
$$
f(x)\qquad f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\qquad f\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)
$$

Comment: +1 upvote! Though solution is easy to devise (as it involves the famous Moebius transform $x \mapsto (1-x)^{-1}$ with order 3), the answer seems somewhat messy: $$f(x) = \frac{49 x^4-273 x^3+240 x^2+22 x-48}{6 x \left(2 x^3-9 x^2+3 x+2\right)}. $$ (This solution is obtained by using Solve method in *Mathematica 8*.)

Comment: It is honor for me to get your upvote

Comment: You're welcome! Anyway, sorry for a wrong answer above. I must have made a typo. Here is a correct answer: $$ f(x) = \frac{3 x^4-31 x^3+60 x^2-6 x-16}{4 x^4-18 x^3+6 x^2+4 x}. $$